# Controlling form's submit behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, google-docs

I am trying to use **Google Docs Form** in a custom HTML page. So far I have generated a form online and extracted the `<form>` part from its source.

It works perfectly so far, except that it transfers the whole page to the confirmation page of Google.

What I would like to achieve is either:

1. not to transfer to the Google confirmation page but just display some small notification that the form has been submitted (for example using Colorbox)
2. or if it is not possible then at least make the confirmation window pup up in a new window with controlled dimensions

#### For explaining my idea

This is the link to the original form's live page:
[original form page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG94WjlHTzljMHdMTEZ1ek1SY0c2NVE6MQ)

Here is the extracted form part:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dG94WjlHTzljMHdMTEZ1ek1SY0c2NVE6MQ&amp;ifq" method="POST" id="ss-form">
    <label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">Sample Question 1</label>
    <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_0"></label>
    <input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0"></div></div></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Is there any way to control how the submit action happens?**

I know `target="_blank"` works for forms too, but I believe there must be more sophisticated control over what happens when someone clicks to the **Submit** button.

**To sum up**

I would like to display the form's confirmation in Colorbox while sending the data to the Google back-end, without showing the Google front-end. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned Colorbox - that's exactly what I use.

All you have to do is open the link to the original form page using the href parameter when you instantiate the Colorbox. Also when you're opening outside pages you need to use iframe mode.

Example:

```
$.colorbox({href:"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG94WjlHTzljMHdMTEZ1ek1SY0c2NVE6MQ", iframe:true});
```

When you submit the form you'll see google's confirmation page within the Colorbox, and then user can easily close it. You should be able to give the colorbox a caption to instruct them if needed. (Using title: ?? Maybe?)

Comment: Also had to mention how great I think Colorbox is ;)

Comment: Sorry, could you provide some example that how should it work? I need to make it work with a `<form>`, not with an `<a href>`

Comment: 1. Click colorbox trigger, 2. Form opens within colorbox, 3. User submits form and sees googles confirmation page inside colorbox. 4. User closes colorbox and is still on the same page as when they started.

Comment: You could also use ajax and you wouldn't need colorbox, but then you have to grab all the field values with javascript and format the request yourself, hide the form after it's sent, display a loading image, parse the response, and display an appropriate message.

Comment: OK, now I understand your point. Colorbox trigger is not an option because I would like to display the form as it is now, constantly. It would be a form for signing up for a mailing list, and I believe its much more efficient if you dont have to click once more. But your solution is an alternative!